# try this in python shell: list.extend/append

Tags: python, list

This is what I just did in python shell:

```
>>>[1, 2]
...[1, 2]
>>>[1, 2].extend([2,3])  #when I pressed Enter
>>>  

                #nothing came out
```

then I tried something else:

```
>>>l = [1, 2]
>>>l
...[1, 2]
>>>m = [1, 2].extend([2, 3])
>>>m                     #pressed Enter, nothing came out
>>>m is None
...True
```

why?
Does it mean, I cannot do something like

```
>>>m = [...].extend(...)
```

?

Comment: list.extend modifies the list **in place**.

Comment: And when a mutable object is modified **in place**, the return value from the function is None.  Not a new object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't, `extend` (as append, pop...) modify the object inplace without returning anything.

The list objects are mutable objects, they can be modified without need to recreate one.

In your case, you have to do

```
>>>l = [1,2]
>>>l.extend([2,3])
>>>l
[1,2,2,3]
```

If you change the type of `l`, assume this is another object, let's call it `class Foo`, what would you expect as return value of something like

```
foo = Foo()
foo.modify_object("here are modifications")
```

Won't you expect something like foo object modified, and nothing returned from the method ?

Comment: Because that's what `extend` returns.

Comment: @Alcott : I add an example with something else than a list

Answer (score 2):

You can always do m = [...] + [...].

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> l.extend([2, 3])
>>> l
[1, 2, 2, 3]
>>>
```

almost all list operations modify the list **in place**, e.g.

```
>>> m = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4]
>>> m.sort()
>>> m
[1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```